# Order of WHERE predicates and the SQL optimizer

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, query-optimization, where-clause

When writting SQL queries with various `where` clauses (I only work with *MySQL* and *sqlite*) , I usually have the doubt of reordering the query clauses to put the "best ones" first (those which will remove a bigger amount of rows), and other "cosmetic" clauses later (which will barely change the output). In other words, I'm in doubt about if I really will help the optimizer to run faster by reordering clauses (specially when there are indexes in play), or if it could be another case of premature optimization. Optimizers are usually smarter than me.

For example:

```
select address.* from address inner join
                      user on address.user = user.id
where address.zip is not null and address.country == user.country
```

If we know that usually `address.zip` is not null, that check will be 90% true, and if the query order is respected, there will be a lot of dummy checks which can be avoided by placing the `country` check before.

Should I take care of that? In other words, is it important the order of `where` clauses or not?

Comment: Which database you are  using  ? ... because your question is not db independent

Comment: @scaisEdge Added a NOTE at the end.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Hard to hear. Why does it sound so bad? (my English is not so good and it's hard to me to know how do my questions sound like).

Comment: @Peregring-lk, your english is more than fine but the question is so out of focus. It should be like a dictionary definition. The main idea should be clear from the first line if not already from the topic. Don't tell stories. Start from the main idea and then drill down using simple and clear examples.

Comment: @Peregring-lkq, check the updated answer regarding MySQL, however read carefully at the end of the previous section

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Question edited with your suggestion. And yes, my students say the same to me, that I'm much a story teller.

Comment: :-)...............

Answer (score 3):

The mysql optimizer  seems well documented  and you can find a many interesting considerations in offcial documents ..http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html

be taken into account especially of a very simple fact .... **sql is not a procedural language but rather is a declarative language** .. this mean it is not important the order in which the parts are written but it is important only the fact of what elements are been declared. This is evident in the documentation on optimization of mysql where where the focus is only on the components of a query and how they are transformed by optmizer  in internal components

Answer (score 1):

The answer is definitly maybe.
Mysterious are the ways of the optimizer.

Here is a demonstration based on exception caused due to division by zero.

```
create table t (i int);
insert into t (i) values (0);
```

The following query succeeds for **Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres** and **Teradata** (we'll skip the version information for now):

```
select 1 from t where i < 1 or 1/i < 1;
```

The following query fails for **SQL Server** and **Postgres** but succeeds for **Oracle** and **Teradata**

```
select 1 from t where 1/i < 1 or i < 1;
```

However, the following query does fail for **Oracle** and **Teradata**:

```
select 1 from t where 1/i < 1 or i/1 < 1;
```

What do we learn?
That some optimizers seem to respect the order of the predicates (or at least in some manner) and some seem to reorder the predicates by their estimated cost (e.g `1/i < 1` is more costly than `i < 1` but not `i/1 < 1`).
For those who respect the order of the predicates we probably can improve performance by putting the light wait predicates first for OR operators and the frequently false predicates for AND operators.
Being that said, since databases do not guarantee to preserve the order of the predicates even if some of them currently seem to do that, you definitly can't count on it.

---

#### MySQL 5.7.11

This query returns immediately:

```
select 1 from t where i < 1 or sleep(3);
```

This query returns after 3 seconds:

```
select 1 from t where sleep(3) or i < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The order is mostly irrelevant.

In MySQL, with `WHERE ... AND ...`,

- The Optimizer will first look for which part can use an index.  If one can and one can't, the optimizer will use the index; the order becomes irrelevant
- If both sides of the `AND` can use an index, MySQL will *usually* pick the 'better' one.  (Sometimes it goofs.)  Again, the order is ignored.
- If neither side can use an index, it it evaluated left to right.  But...  Fetching rows is the bulk of effort in performing the query, so if one side of the `AND` is a little slower than the other, you *probably* won't notice.  (Sure, if one side does `SLEEP(3)` you will notice.)

There's another issue in your example query (aside from the syntax error):  The Optimizer will make a conscious decision of which table to start with.

- If it decides to start with `user`, `address` needs `INDEX(user, country)` in either order.
- If it decides to start with `address`, `user` needs `(id, country)` in either order.
- It is unclear whether the Optimizer will bother with the `NOT NULL` test, even if that column is indexed.

Bottom line:  Spend your time focusing on [*optimal indexes*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .